# Swift enum with nested enum, how implement associated values from String of RawRepresentable protocol

Tags: swift, enums

Here is my code

```
enum AccountType : String{
    
    enum Pattern : String{
        case oneTimePassword
        case password
    }
    
    enum ThirdServicePattern : String{
        case facebook
        case google
        case line
        case signInWithApple
    }
    
    case phoneNumber(pattern : Pattern)

    case email(pattern : Pattern)

    case thirdService(pattern : ThirdServicePattern)
    
}
```

How about the implementation of the `RawRepresentable` protocol?

When you add `String` for `AccountType`, there is an error "enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments", even if I declare `rawValue` myself, it still fails to compile.

```
enum AccountType : String{
    
    enum BasePattern : String{
        case oneTimePassword
        case password
    }
    
    enum ThirdServicePattern : String{
        case facebook
        case google
        case line
        case signInWithApple
    }
    
    case phoneNumber(BasePattern) //enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments

    case email(BasePattern) //enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments

    case thirdService(ThirdServicePattern) //enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments
    
}


extension AccountType : RawRepresentable {

    typealias RawValue = String
    
    /// Backing raw value
     var rawValue: RawValue {
        return "How?"
     }
    
    /// Failable Initalizer
    init?(rawValue: String) {
        switch rawValue {
        case ".PhoneNumber(.oneTimePassword)":  self = .phoneNumber(BasePattern.oneTimePassword)
        case ".PhoneNumber(.password)":  self = .phoneNumber(BasePattern.password)
        case ".Email(.oneTimePassword)":  self = .email(BasePattern.oneTimePassword)
        case ".Email(.password)":  self = .email(BasePattern.password)
        case ".thirdService(.facebook)":  self = .thirdService(ThirdServicePattern.facebook)
        case ".thirdService(.google)":  self = .thirdService(ThirdServicePattern.google)
        case ".thirdService(.line)":  self = .thirdService(ThirdServicePattern.line)
            
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

What's the rule for raw value regarding nested enum in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly fine for an enum with associated values tp conform to `RawRepresentable`, but *you have to manually do it*, which you did, so that's fine.

However, enums with associated values cannot have a *raw type*:

```
enum AccountType : String{
```

You must write:

```
enum AccountType {
```

instead. Note that you don't lose anything by removing `: String` in this case, because all `: String` does, is make `AccountType` conform to `RawRepresentable` automatically (the error occurs because the compiler can't automatically do it for enums with associated values). Well, you *already* conformed to `RawRepresentable` manually, so there's no need for `: String` in the first place!

Note that this has nothing to do with nested enums, and all to do with enums with associated values.